# tuplex out of range when working with buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program which works fine but when i try to do it with buttons,when i run it,it gives me

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in **call**
>
> ```
> return self.func(*args)   File "fire_buttons.py", line 193, in Plot
>
> result=la.Graph(grids)   File "fire_buttons.py", line 181, in Graph
>
> n=sc.shape(data)[2] IndexError: tuple index out of range
> ```

The function is that:

```
 def Graph(self,data):
            """Make the plot"""
            plt.colormaps()
            n=sc.shape(data)[2]
            ims=[]
            for i in range(n):
                mydata=data[:,:,i]
                im=plt.imshow(mydata,cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
                ims.append([im])
            return ims
```

Some code for the buttons:

```
def createWidgets(self):
        """Add widgets to main frame"""
        top_frame=Frame(self)
        self.Tree=StringVar()
        self.Tree_entry=Entry(top_frame,textvariable=self.Tree)
        self.label1=Label(top_frame,text="Probability of existence of a tree")
        self.Tree_entry.pack(side='right')
        self.label1.pack()
        top_frame.pack(side=TOP)
   ......
        bottom_frame=Frame(self)
        bottom_frame.pack(side=TOP)
        self.QUIT=Button(bottom_frame,text='Quit',command=self.quit)
        self.QUIT.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.operate=Button(bottom_frame,text='Run',command=self.Plot)
        self.operate.pack(side=LEFT)

def Plot(self):
        if (self.area.get().isdigit() and p.match(self.Tree.get())  and p.match(self.Burning.get())  and p.match(self.Lighting.get()) and p.match(self.ResistBurn.get()) and p.match(self.RegenerateTree.get()) and self.time_step.get().isdigit()):   
            la=myfire()
            grids=la.fire(int(self.area.get()),float(self.Tree.get()),float(self.Burning.get()),float(self.Lighting.get()),float(self.ResistBurn.get()),float(self.RegenerateTree.get()),int(self.time_step.get()))
            result=la.Graph(grids)
            fig=plt.gcf()
            ArtistAnimation(fig,result,interval=10,repeat=False)
            plt.show()
```

Also,if i want to use slide widget i tried sth like:

```
self.Tree_entry=Scale(top_frame,from_=0,to=1,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=1000, tickinterval=0.001)
self.Tree_entry.set(40)
```

I want values from 0 to 1 and increment by 0.0001.But this just gives me 0 and 1 only.

--------------------UPDATE--------------------

In the version without the buttons instead of Plot function i use:

```
grids=fire(area,Tree,Burning,Lighting,ResistBurn,RegenerateTree,time_step)
result=Graph(grids)
fig=plt.gcf()
ani=ArtistAnimation(fig,result,interval=10,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

and it runs fine,so maybe i have sth wrong in the Plot?

Comment: Is `grids = fire(...)` the same as `la=myfire(); grids = la.fire(...)`?

Comment: @gary comtois:The whole code is in a class "myfire".In the version without the buttons i don't use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is on this line:

```
n=sc.shape(data)[2]
```

From the evidence you've given, this has nothing to do with buttons or widgets in any way.  You're simply trying to get element 2 from a tuple but the tuple doesn't have that many elements. You need to find where you define sc.shape(data) and see why it doesn't have as many items as you think it should.

Comment: :But the program runs fine without the buttons.I use Plot function only for the button version.I am updating in a moment.

Comment: @george: regardless, that is the error python is reporting, and python usually doesn't lie about errors. Perhaps when you add or remove the buttons you are also changing some other part of the code, or the code is running before some other code that is a dependency. Always start debugging with the actual error. Ask yourself "why is that tuple smaller than I think it is?"

Answer (score 2):

Your first question might be answered by getting the size of `grids`, prior to using it in the `la.Graph(grids)` line of code. Perhaps it's just a tuple with a single item? (Or less than three anyway, since `[2]` is giving the error.)

**EDIT:** <s>Your second question needs `to=100` I believe.</s> I misread that you wanted to go between 0 and 1. You may be only seeing 0 or 1 since you set the value to 40.

**EDIT:** The following has been tested.

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    tree_entry = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution=0.001)
    tree_entry.pack()

    tree_entry.set(0.5)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image: yay tkinter]

Comment: :the problem is that still can select only 0 or 1.Doesn't have intermediate values.As for the first if i try to put a print statement in the code it doesn't show me the result.